# Computing $V(p_1, p_2)$ and determining whether $V(p_1) \subset V(p_2)$

Tags: geometry, algebra

Say I have two homogeneous polynomials $p_1, p_2 \in \mathbb{C}[x_0, \dots, x_n]$. In other words, they cut out co-dimension 1 varieties in $\mathbb{P}^n$. I would like to know how to compute two things in Mathematica:

1. (a representation of) the intersection of the two varieties $V(p_1, p_2)$,
2. Whether $V(p_1) \subset V(p_2)$.

I understand from Hilbert's Nullstellensatz that these translate to statements about (radical) ideals, and I would be fine with a program that computes using whatever representation allows for effective algorithms on small examples. I do not need to visualize the results, I am just looking for small examples with specific properties and want to do an exhaustive search.

Comment: You should provide an explicit example, e.g. the polynomials in Mathematica input form.

Answer (score 3):

`V(p1)⊂V(p2)`iff the radical of the ideal `(p2)` contains that of `(p1)`. These radicals are, for principal ideals, generated by the squarefree factors of the respective generating polynomials.

The intersection can be found using a construct like `Solve[{p1==0,p2==0},vars]`. If instead you want the ideal intersection, that can be found by a `GroebnerBasis` construction.